# Duplicate type names between bing.speech and CLRHost.dll in C#/WinRT app?

Tags: c#, types, visual-studio-2013

I have a user control that uses the Bing.Speech Extension library.  It is in its own project and the control so far has only been consumed by the main app I've been working on, another project in the same Solution.  It's been working fine for a few weeks now.  Today I created a new Solution with it to run some tests away from my main app.  When I included it in the new solution, as expected many of the References were not resolved, one of them being to Bing.Speech.  I enabled NuGet package restore for the solution, cleaned and rebuilt it.  Now I'm getting numerous errors about duplicate type names as you can see below.  Apparently some conflict with the CLRHost.dll in-process server?  What can I do to fix this?

```
Error   5   The .winmd file 'Bing.Speech.winmd' contains duplicate type names. Type 'Bing.Speech.SpeechAuthorizationParameters' is already registered with the in-process server 'CLRHost.dll'. TestSpeechRecoControl

Error   4   The .winmd file 'Bing.Speech.winmd' contains duplicate type names. Type 'Bing.Speech.SpeechRecognitionAudioCaptureStateChangedEventArgs' is already registered with the in-process server 'CLRHost.dll'.    TestSpeechRecoControl

Error   6   The .winmd file 'Bing.Speech.winmd' contains duplicate type names. Type 'Bing.Speech.SpeechRecognitionAudioLevelChangedEventArgs' is already registered with the in-process server 'CLRHost.dll'.   TestSpeechRecoControl

Error   8   The .winmd file 'Bing.Speech.winmd' contains duplicate type names. Type 'Bing.Speech.SpeechRecognitionResultReceivedEventArgs' is already registered with the in-process server 'CLRHost.dll'.  TestSpeechRecoControl

Error   7   The .winmd file 'Bing.Speech.winmd' contains duplicate type names. Type 'Bing.Speech.SpeechRecognizer' is already registered with the in-process server 'CLRHost.dll'.  TestSpeechRecoControl
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same error message but in another situation.
For universal windows app(where bing speech referenced) was made test project. And in this test project I have compilation exception

Error   8   The .winmd file 'Bing.Speech.winmd' contains duplicate type names. Type 'Bing.Speech.SpeechRecognitionResultReceivedEventArgs' is already registered with the in-process server 'CLRHost.dll'.  Windows.Tests

In my case when the reference to bing.speeck was added the problem was solved